# Angular datatables hide column

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am willing to hide some columns (actually from the example below the column with index 6) from user view but still want to have them in the DOM to make search access the values.

I use `DTColumnDefBuilder`:

```
$scope.dtColumnDefsTabs = [
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable(),
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1),
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).withOption('orderDataType', 'content-categories'),
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3).withOption('orderDataType', 'markers'),
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4).notSortable(),
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5).notSortable().withClass('no-background-image'),
                DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).withOption('visible', 'false')
            ];
```

In the `<thead>` html I define empty `<td>`:

```
<th></th>
```

And add data in the `<tbody>`:

```
<td>{{ entry.device.device }}</td>
```

So I tried all possibilities which I could find:

```
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).withOption('visible', 'false')

DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).withOption('visible', false)

$scope.dtColumnDefsTabs[6].visible = false;

DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).notVisible()
```

Nothing worked, the column is still displayed.

P. S. All columns from (id=0) to (id=5) fill the whole table width (every `<td>` has a css `width` setting)

P. P. S. I don't want to show the column with `responsive: true` option.

Comment: create jsfiddle or make full example here on SO.

Comment: did you look at ng-show directive?

Comment: @epitka `ng-show` did the trick. Can you please make you comment to an answer? I would like to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-show directive to show and hide element, but keep it in DOM.

Comment: Angular documentation has examples.

Comment: How to possibly this in ajax data-table?

Comment: @JaiKumaresh add  "visible": false in  "columnDefs".

Answer (score 4):

**The Datatable API for visible** :   column().visible();

**Reference link** :    https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()

**Example Code** :
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("columname").withTitle("column title").withOption('visible', false),

Answer (score 3):

if you are working on type script file ,
you can do like this

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
```

Comment: Best professional way, tried with Angular 5 when defining `dtOptions: this.dtOptions = { order:[1,'asc'],columnDefs:[ { "targets": [ 3 ],"visible": false }] };`  Bravo !

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.dtcolumns[0].visible = false
```

Comment: It's work with column, but if we use the `withLightColumnFilter()` function, the filter is not hidden. There is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but I got this working by setting a class like:

```
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('hiddencol').withClass('hiddencol'),
    ...
]
```

Then, use CSS to hide it.

```
.hiddencol {
    display: none;
}
```